# SFINAE Template Error

Tags: c++, sfinae, ros

I'm using SFINEA to subscribe to generic topics in ROS, that listens to every topic, and uses SFINEA to return the `header.stamp` time if one exists. This works much quicker the deserialization. The only issue is I'm having an issue getting my subscriber set up. I keep getting the following compile error:

```
CMakeFiles/performance_tracker.dir/src/performance_tracker.cpp.o: 
In function   PerformanceTracker::topicCallback(boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>)
ros/src/performance_tracker/src/performance_tracker.cpp:32:
undefined reference to boost::disable_if<timewarp::has_header<boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> >, ros::Time>::type
timewarp::extractTime<boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> >(boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>)
```

**Main**

```
 // Subscribe To Generic Message 
 _sub =  _nh.subscribe( _topicName, 1, &PerformanceTracker::topicCallback, this);


void PerformanceTracker::topicCallback(const boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> data){
//Current Time
ros::Time begin = ros::Time::now();
ros::Time timePublished = timewarp::extractTime<boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>>(data);
}
```

***NAMESPACE CLASS***

```
namespace timewarp
{
template <typename T>
struct has_header {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename C>
    static yes& test(typename C::_header_type*);

    template <typename>
    static no& test(...);

    // If the "sizeof" the result of calling test<T>(0) would be equal to the sizeof(yes),
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template<class MsgType>
typename boost::enable_if<has_header<MsgType>, ros::Time>::type extractTime(const boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> data)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<MsgType> ptr = data->instantiate<MsgType>();
    assert(ptr);

    return ptr->header.stamp;
}

template<class MsgType>
typename boost::disable_if<has_header<MsgType>, ros::Time>::type extractTime(const boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>` type as MsgType to `has_header<T>` instead of `topic_tools::ShapeShifter`.

I believe you want to do:

```
ros::Time timePublished = timewarp::extractTime<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>(data);
```

And use const refs arguments while you're at it :)

```
template<class MsgType>
typename boost::enable_if<has_header<MsgType>, ros::Time>::type extractTime(const boost::shared_ptr<MsgType>& data)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<MsgType> ptr = data->instantiate<MsgType>();
    assert(ptr);

    return ptr->header.stamp;
}

template<class MsgType>
typename boost::disable_if<has_header<MsgType>, ros::Time>::type extractTime(const boost::shared_ptr<MsgType>&)
{
    return ros::Time::now(); 
    // or whatever ros time you need to return for types without headers
}
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but I put `boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>` as the data type in my SFINAE method, so why would does passing the generic `topic_tools::ShapeShifter` work ?

Comment: Also the second one returns `error: expected primary-expression before const ros::Time timePublished = timewarp::extractTime(const boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>& data);`

Comment: And the first one returns the same error. Is this a linking issue?

Comment: I sitll get  with the constant reference, and the first one without:`In function PerformanceTracker::topicCallback(boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> const&):
/ros/src/performance_tracker/src/performance_tracker.cpp:31: undefined reference to boost::disable_if<timewarp::has_header<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>, ros::Time>::type timewarp::extractTime<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>(boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> const&)'` Maybe this is a linker issue?

Comment: I updated my comment where I clarified what I meant with const ref. The issue with passing `boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>` is that this type is passed to `extractTime` as `MsgType` which then is pass to `has_header` as T which again is passed to `test` as `C` and there the compiler checks if `C` has the member `_header_type`. Now, since `C` is of type `boost::shared_ptr<...>` it will never contain the member `_header_type`.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! That makes perfect sense ! Let me try this again

Comment: Should I just change my method type to pass a `topic_tools:ShapeShifter` without any boost_pointer wrappers? I'm not too familiar with boost and it seems that is where the confusion is

Comment: for some reason, your edits worked but only after adding a {} to the `disable_if` method